# AudioKit AKWaveTable initialization error

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am having a weird problem initializing AudioKit AKWaveTable node.
I am trying to change the sample rate of a sound on the fly and I thought AKWaveTable would be the best option to do this.
According to the documentation, this initialization function already sets default parameters for most of the parameters, so I would only need to give it a filename:

```
self.file=try  AKAudioFile(readFileName: fileName)
self.player=AKWaveTable(file: self.file)
```

I get the following error upon running app:

> 2018-10-21 17:22:29.276450+0200 AKSoundPool[1479:44079] [default]
>   Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides) 2018-10-21
>   17:22:29.570701+0200 AKSoundPool[1479:44079] [AudioHAL_Client]
>   AudioHardware.cpp:666:AudioObjectGetPropertyData: 
>   AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
>   AKWaveTable.swift:init(file:startPoint:endPoint:rate:volume:maximumSamples:completionHandler:loadCompletionHandler:):218:Parameter
>   Tree Failed 2018-10-21 17:22:29.607702+0200 AKSoundPool[1479:44079]
>   [avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false:
>   [AVAudioEngine.mm:393:AttachNode: (node != nil)] 2018-10-21
>   17:22:29.609506+0200 AKSoundPool[1479:44079] required condition is
>   false: node != nil

I also tried setting all of the other parameters to 0 but I get the same error, parameter tree failed.

Any hints? Am I on the wrong track?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling **App Sandbox** in your project configuration.
In **XCode** it's under "**capabilities**". 
I had the same issue and my app was in a sandbox where some key features needed for AudioKit were disabled.

Comment: what sense would this make if I want my app on the app store? Does iOS have the same problem? Havent tried on iOS yet.. Can someone working in AudioKit confirm this?